# php not returning any result to javascript ajax object

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to use ajax, I've used it before, copied the code from my previous html file and altered the values sent, php file to process the code and I'm using the POST method. However, the php script does not return anything to the html page. I've checked all i can, so I'm here now.
    function look () {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('option')[document.getElementById("region").selectedIndex].value;
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

```
 try{
   // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
   ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
 }catch (e){
   // Internet Explorer Browsers
   try{
  ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
   }catch (e) {
      try{
     ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }catch (e){
     // Something went wrong
     alert("Your browser broke!");
     return false;
  }
  }
}
   // Create a function that will receive data 
 // sent from the server and will update
 // modal section in the same page.
 ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
      var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById("accordion");
  ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
}
}
   // Now get the value from user and pass it to
 // server script.
 ajaxRequest.open("POST", "search.php", true);
 ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 alert(x);
 ajaxRequest.send("region=" + x);

}
```

The php code is a simple

```
<?php
echo "The world is blue.";
?>
```

yet, it returns nothing to the chosen div.

Comment: First of all, I'd suggest using a framework like jQuery, it makes things a lot easier with AJAX. Secondly, are you sure you are getting results from PHP?

Comment: That's the issue, I am not getting any results from php. I have another application that works just fine with this, however, this one is just not returning anything to a div with id "accordion".

Comment: @Michael You php is primitive and must work. Try to use firebug for your javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably not posted enough information for us to answer your question. But, I acknowledge that you probably are not sure what questions you need to ask in the first place.

First, I must agree with @cgf. jQuery or the alike will make this easier.

But lets focus on the problem at hand.  We need to know what is happening behind the scenes.

The best way to do this is through a developer tool bar such as firebug. Chrome has one built in.

So, load up chrome and hit <kbd>F12</kbd>. This should bring up a very busy looking pane on the bottom of your window. Select the **Network** tab and then request your page / trigger your javascript. What output do you get in the network tab? Mainly, under status do you get 200, 500 (server error) or perhaps 404 (not found)? Update your question above with what you see / get.

My hope is that this *should* point you in the right direction.

Comment: I get 200 OK in the status column when I trigger the javascript function, however, nothing is returned to the div. And, if I may add, there's no information missing, I have a div with an id of accordion where the result from php should be inserted.

Comment: @Michael, so did you try something like `alert(ajaxResults)` ? Basically checking if you're just not showing it properly in HTML or you are not getting anything from the PHP script?

Comment: yeah, I've done that and php isn't returning anything.

Comment: Well, what do you get when you retrieve the php page via a browser directly? Also, how are you loading the page with the javascript? Given that you are using a relative path (`ajaxRequest.open("POST", "search.php", true)`), you'll need to request the page with the javascript via localhost (or wherever your php file is)

Comment: All files are in the same folder on my localhost. There's nothing out of the ordinary. A search button is clicked, and onclick, the look() function is called, it alerts me to show the value before it is passed, and then php just doesn't return anything, if it is even called in the first place.

Comment: @Michael I need more info. A few things remain unclear. When you run the php via local host such as http://localhost/search.php does the content get returned to the browser? (note, you may need to view source since there is no HTML.) Lets start with this and go from there...

Comment: When I run the php, it returns the string it's supposed to return, the php file is above anyway, so, I think u'd find that there's nothing complex about the code, anyway, I'm just going to use JQuery as this has never happened to anybody here before. The worst part is that I used it on another project just last month. It's amazing.

Comment: Another thing is that my javascript is in a php file. That shouldn't be an issue anayway cos it worked on another php file.